# <JAVA> How to take the RGB pixel values of the whole screen in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, pixel, javacv

This is my code so far but i get errors like `OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (index is out of range) in cvPtr2D, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 1797
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:1797: error: (-211) index is out of range in function cvPtr2D`

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated ;)

```
    cvNamedWindow("OpenCV", 0);
    while(true)
    {
        IplImage img = cvQueryFrame(cvCreateCameraCapture(0));
        CvScalar[] s = new CvScalar[img.height()*img.width()+2];
        for(int i = 0;i<=img.width();i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<=img.height();j++)
            {
                s[j] = cvGet2D(img, i, j);
            }
        }
        cvShowImage("OpenCV", img);
        cvWaitKey(33);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvGet2D()` expects row before column. And the index is 0-based, so your loops are just out of bounds. And `s` should probably be a 2D array, so you don't keep overwriting your data. Try this:

```
CvScalar[][] s = new CvScalar[img.height()][img.width()];
for (int i = 0; i < img.height(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < img.width(); j++) {
        s[i][j] = cvGet2D(img, i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but my application is running a bit slower than usual. Is there any way i can increase the speed of my application?

Comment: That's an entirely separate question, and a very broad one, if I may say. When you can narrow it down to specific problem with a specific piece of code, post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel =)